# Prevent PHP Interpreting New Lines in Strings in the Source Code

Tags: php, string, coding-style, string-formatting, code-formatting

I often have to assign large strings to variables. In the source code I preferably want to keep my lines within 80 characters.

Ideally I want to be able to lay these literal strings out on multiple lines.

What I want to avoid is using concatenation, or function calls (e.g. `preg_replace()`), to join multiple strings together in one. I don't like the idea that I have to invoke language features in order to improve the style of my code.

Example of something I would like:

```
    $text = <<<TEXT
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
TEXT;
    echo($text);
```

This should output:

```
Line1Line2Line3
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You cannot really avoid working around string concatenation for this one... A newline in a multiline string is a newline.

Comment: Ive read this 3 times and it still makes no sense. Do you want to strip the newlines so the browser source sees no new lines?

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone: OPs Coding Conventions deny him from using lines of code longer than 80 characters, so he wants to split them

Comment: `str_replace(PHP_EOL, "");`? You are using heredoc formatting. You can't get around the absence of formatting...

Comment: @LawrenceCherone That's roughly it. More precisely I was hoping for a way to make the PHP interpreter ignore the new line characters.

Comment: @Hiroto It doesn't necessarily need to be heredoc, it was just an example. Any literal string would do if it does what I need it to.

Comment: @Fractal the thing about PHP's interpreter is that anything inside string delimiters is treated as a string, while whitespace outside of it is treated as whitespace and ignored. There's no way that I know of to actually treat `T_STRING` as anything else. You'd be better off using a function or concat, really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options:

1. Just concatenate (preferred)
2. Use `array` constructs
3. Use `sprintf()`

**Just concatenate:**

```
echo 'long long line1'
    . 'another long line 2'
    . 'the last very long line 3';
```

> What about efficiency?

The above code compiles into the following opcodes (which is what's run):

```
5    0  >   CONCAT      ~0      'long+long+line1', 'another+long+line+2'
     1      CONCAT      ~1  ~0, 'the+last+very+long+line+3'
     2      ECHO        ~1
```

As you can see, it builds the string by concatenating the first two lines, followed by the last line; in the end `~0` is discarded. In terms of memory, the difference is negligible.

This is what a single `echo` statement would look like:

```
3    0  >   ECHO                'long+long+line1another+long+line+2the+last+very+long+line+3'
```

Technically it's faster because there are no intermediate steps, but in reality you won't feel that difference at all.

**Using `array`:**

```
echo join('', array(
    'line 1',
    'line 2',
    'line 3',
));
```

**Using `sprintf()`:**

```
echo sprintf('%s%s%s',
    'line 1',
    'line 2',
    'line 3'
);
```

Comment: And there is no reason to prefer 1st and 2nd over 3rd ) At least they don't bring any obvious benefits

Comment: @zerkms What about efficiency?

Comment: @Fractal: until you concatenate less than several millions of strings - you have nothing to worry about

Comment: @Fractal I've highlighted the efficiency part.

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = 'Line1'.
        'Line2'.
        'Line3';

var_dump($text);
```

This way you'll have your code split over several lines, but the data itself is a single line.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to concatenate strings but the problem is not the length of the string nor formatting its that you are mixing large amounts of markup with php.

IMO Really if the core logic of your application contains large amount of html then you should perhaps think about moving it out of the logic and load it from an external file, this way it will improve readability of your code.

**./your_view.php**

```
<h1>This is my view, I only want small amounts of PHP here, values will be passed to me</h1>
<p><?php echo $somevar;?></p>
```

Now within your core logic you would perhaps have a global function that loads your view and passes data to it. then you can control the removal of new lines.

**index.php (or such logic file)**

```
<?php
function load_view($path,$data,$minify=false) {
    if (file_exists($path) === false){
        return false;
    }
    extract($data);
    ob_start();
    require($path);
    $out = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    //you can remove all the new lines here
    if($minify===true){
        return preg_replace('/^\s+|\n|\r|\s+$/m', '', $out);
    }else{
        return $out;
    }
}

$data = array('somevar'=>'This is some data that I want to pass to a block of html');

echo load_view('./your_view.php',$data,true);
?>
```

Comment: Why do you think OP runs the script under webserver and not in, say, CLI? How HTML and templating is related to the question? You sill have some long string that OP wanted to aboid. Definitely not an answer.

Comment: PS: your `$minify` thing would break the data - you just **cannot** remove new lines out of context. Newlines in HTML is a significant character - it may change the result.